# Cisco ASA Clientless SSL VPN Apply Tunnel Group

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, sslvpn

I'm trying to implement the answer from a previous question I've asked ([Cisco ASA Clientless SSL VPN Restrict Network Access](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77016/cisco-asa-clientless-ssl-vpn-restrict-network-access))

My ultimate aim is to set up an SSL VPN on a Cisco ASA device to allow access to a specific DMZ area for clients of an imaginary company (uni project).

I've added the below lines to the config but I'm stuck with how to "apply" or "enable" this tunnel group separately from the default webvpn enabled in the first lines. Do I apply it to the outside interface somehow, or is it something to do with the IP Address/URL that the user uses to access the service?

```
webvpn
enable outside
exit

access-list CLIENT-VPN-LIST extended permit tcp object net-outside object net-dmz-client-server eq 3389
access-list CLIENT-VPN-LIST extended deny ip any any

group-policy CLIENT-VPN-POLICY internal
group-policy CLIENT-VPN-POLICY attributes
vpn-filter value CLIENT-VPN-LIST

tunnel-group CLIENT-VPN-GROUP type webvpn
tunnel-group CLIENT-VPN-GROUP general-attributes
authorization-required
default-group-policy CLIENT-VPN-POLICY
```

Edited to remove various outputs requested to help me get things correct that will only make this question confusing.

Comment: I assumed on the previous question that you at least had the rest of the tunnel-group defined already.  Can you type `show run all tunnel-group` and show me the output so I can see what you do have?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it into the original, thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  I’ll take a look and respond in a little bit. Gotta get my oldest kid to school.

Comment: I don't see any definitions in what you've already provided but, just to be safe, can you please show me the outputs from `show webvpn group-url` and `show webvpn group-alias`?  Also, your users will need to go to *something* to access the VPN login page, which is usually a URL with an FQDN with or without a group/alias (such as `https://vpn.company.com` or `https://vpn.company.com/group`), but could just be a URL with an IP address and group/alias (such as `https://100.200.100.200/group`).  Please clarify what it is that your users go (will go) to, to access the VPN.

Comment: Nothing shows up for either of those show commands. Sorry I'm a bit out of my depth with this stuff. For accessing the VPN so far I have just been navigating to the IP address for the outside interface. I'd probably just stick to the IP address plus a group/alias to keep it simple.

Comment: That's okay.  That’s exactly what I expected. I added an answer to explain your next steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't currently have any group-url or group-alias definitions on any tunnel-groups, your users will use DefaultWEBVPNGroup's settings, which use local authentication (rather than something like RADIUS, TACACS, or LDAP) and will use the default group-policy DfltGrpPolicy.

Because of this, you have 3 options.

**Option 1**: You can edit DfltGrpPolicy so that it uses the VPN filter you previously created (alternatively you could also set it to use different authentication methods).  If you do this, it will also affect your site-to-site tunnel and anything else using DfltGrpPolicy (because you don't have another policy defined for them to use instead).

To do so, you can type:

```
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-filter value CLIENT-VPN-LIST
```

**Note: I strongly recommend against Option 1.**

**Option 2**: You can edit DefaultWEBVPNGroup so that it uses a different group-policy than the tunnel-groups for DefaultRAGroup, DefaultL2LGroup, and 10.1.1.2, so they won't be impacted.

To do so, you can type:

```
tunnel-group DefaultWEBVPNGroup general-attributes
 default-group-policy CLIENT-VPN-POLICY
```

**Note: Option 2 is okay to use if you want there to be a catch-all for users that don't use a group-alias or group-url to direct them somewhere more specific, but I usually don't recommend modifying it for most setups.**

**Option 3**: You can use the tunnel-group you already previously created, called CLIENT-VPN-GROUP, and add a group-alias to it so that users can be mapped to the appropriate policy.

To do so, you can type:

```
tunnel-group CLIENT-VPN-GROUP webvpn-attributes
 group-alias vpn enable
```

If you choose Option 3, users would then be able to access your VPN by going to a URL such as `https://<public IP address>/vpn`.  As long as the `/vpn` is appended to the end, it will map the users to the tunnel-group that is configured with that alias/group and subsequently map them to the appropriate policy.

**Edit**:
It was my mistake for forgetting that clientless VPN doesn't use vpn-filters like client VPN does, and you have to use a WebType ACL to filter traffic based on either URL or TCP-based destinations.

You can still keep the existing VPN-filter in place in case you want the same filtering on a client as well, but it can't be the same ACL since they're different types, meaning you will have 2 ACLs to maintain if you want to make modifications later.  Another caveat is that WebType ACLs can't use objects or object-groups - they need to be literal.

To create a WebType ACL, you can add the following to your policy:

```
access-list CLIENT-VPN-LIST-WebType webtype permit tcp host 192.168.50.2 eq 3389
access-list CLIENT-VPN-LIST-WebType webtype deny tcp any
access-list CLIENT-VPN-LIST-WebType webtype deny url any
```

And then to add it to your existing group-policy, you can type:

```
group-policy CLIENT-VPN-POLICY attributes
 webvpn
  filter value CLIENT-VPN-LIST-WebType
```

You will need to log out of the VPN portal and back in for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go as soon as I can get back to it!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having problems with it. I've gone with option 3 but needed to add a group-url, which works in that going to that url gives me a logon page. However once i log on I can still access all DMZs. I've experimented by adding a deny all ACL to the default policy to test if I was ending up under that policy but that did not block anything. Could it be something to do with using a local user account? I'll drop the full config in the original question.

Comment: @DavidM No, it doesn’t have anything to do with the authentication method.  I’m not sure you can use an IP address as a group-url at all since it expects an FQDN (which is why I suggested using a group-alias).  Any particular reason why you chose to use group-url instead of group-alias?

Comment: @DavidM If you want to see which policy your VPN user is mapped to, you can see that as part of the output from `show vpn-sessiondb webvpn` once your user is connected.  There will be a line that says Group Policy.

Comment: @DavidM It looks like you have both group-url and group-alias configured. What happens when you go to `https://192.168.20.2` and then select `clientvpn` from the drop-down menu it should show you?

Comment: I don't see a dropdown menu either on the login page or the landing page when I log in?

Comment: @DavidM Can you log into the VPN and then use the command I listed above to see which policy you’re being mapped to?

Comment: Sorry, i missed the first comment. It's showing the user as logged in under the CLIENT-VPN-POLICY and the CLIENT-VPN-GROUP. So at least that part is working

Comment: @DavidM Yeah. That’s good. So, give me an example of something else you’re able to hit that should be blocked by the vpn-filter.

Comment: For example if I type in the address of an http server I have running in another DMZ that should be forbideen in the navigation box in the landing page (192.168.40.2) I can access it.

Comment: @DavidM My bad. I forgot that clientless VPN doesn't use vpn-filter (that's for client (AnyConnect and IPSec VPN) filtering). For clientless, you have to use a WebType ACL to filter traffic to specific URLs or TCP-based destinations. I edited the answer above to show you what to do.

Comment: I've now got that implemented but now I cannot access any resources at all i get "Access to this resource has been denied" for both 192.168.40.2 and 192.168.50.2...

Comment: @DavidM What did you implement and what are you typing in to the browse field on the portal? The permit statement allows you to access RDP on the destination and the denies would block everything else.  I verified it works on an ASA I manage, so I’m not sure where you’re getting stuck at.

Comment: Turns out I was stuck because I wasn't thinking, just copy pasting :P I had assumed that the port 3389 related to the VPN traffic not RDP. Once I changed the rule to port 80 (I was accessing a simple proof of concept webserver) it worked. Thank you so much for your help and patience. I'll mark the question answered and try to edit the queston to show a coherant explanation. Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidM Not a problem. Happy to help.